# tiny mce mentions plugin is having problem hitting server url in fetch call

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, richtext

I am using tiny mce 6 through cloud API, and need to do a basic implementation of mentions plugin to bring users list, however when I call one of the routes on my server to get the users, the network tab in browser shows that the url is found 302 but then it never reaches the actual method which is returning users list.

For understanding, suppose below is the URL:

```
var mentionsUrl = '/' + abc + '/getUsers?query=' + query.term + '&param1=' + param1 + '&param2=' + param2;
```

And below is the code block from tiny mce code for mentions that I need to make work, notice the fetch call, which is taking the route :

```
mentions_fetch: (query, success) => {
    // Fetch your full user list from the server and cache locally
    debugger;
    var usersRequest = null;
    if (usersRequest === null) {
        var mentionsUrl = '/' + abc + '/getUsers?query=' + query.term + '&param1=' + param1 + '&param2=' + param2;
            result;

        console.log("getting user data");
        usersRequest = fetch(mentionsUrl);
    }

    usersRequest.then((users) => {
        //users = users.slice(0, 10);

        // Where the user object must contain the properties `id` and `name`
        // but you could additionally include anything else you deem useful.
        success(users);
    });
}
```

The route I am trying to hit is a get ajax route which is returning ajax response containing a list of users.

I need to know what is the issue here ? Is fetch() function expecting a simple get route ?

What is the type of response that fetch() call is expecting from the server?

As per debugging, fetch() call is supposed to return a promise, which then should be calling .then((users)) function as in above code, but in my case promise stays in pending state, since route is never hit properly.

I need to get the users list, so user can choose from it to mention.